# Eclipse Plugin - get Launch Configurations Tree List in a Dialog.

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently trying to get the red part of the "RunConfigurations..." window, (see img 1.1)
into an TitleAreaDialog (see img 1.2).
The final result should look like this:  (see img 1.3)

img 1.1
[image: img 1.1 Run Configurations window] img 1.2

[image: img 1.2 Title Area Dialog]

img 1.3

[image: img 1.3 final result]

With the plugin "Spy" I found some useful information:
The "Run Configurations..." window (img 1.1) is created in the class: "LaunchConfigurationsDialog" which has a "LaunchConfigurationView" as an attribute (note: this attribute is a class).
Within this private attribute you find a "LaunchConfigurationFilteredTree" attribute (note: yet another class).

I think, that this last attribute is what I'm looking for. But I can't figure out which methods I have to override to be able to show this FilteredTreeList with all Launch Configurations in my CustomTitleAreaDialog.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the classes you have found are in **internal** packages and are therefore not part of the Eclipse API (see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)). These classes may be changed at any time breaking your plug-in.

The core of the view does use official APIs.

First it gets the `ILaunchManager`:

```java
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
```

The root elements of the tree are the `ILaunchConfigurationType` entries:

```java
ILaunchConfigurationType [] allTypes = manager.getLaunchConfigurationTypes();
```

The children of `ILaunchConfigurationType` are the actual `ILaunchConfiguration` launch configuration objects:

```java
ILaunchConfiguration [] configs = manager.getLaunchConfigurations(configType);
```

If you build a `TreeViewer` using these methods you will be OK.