# Eclipse Plugin: Is there a way to get the External Tools Configurations Tree?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, launch-configuration

Is there a way to get the orange-highlighted tree(see img) of the "External Tools Configurations..." window?

If not, which classes of the official Eclipse-API can I use to build my own TreeViewer?

This question [here: Eclipse Plugin - get Launch Configurations Tree List in a Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052708/eclipse-plugin-get-launch-configurations-tree-list-in-a-dialog) is similar to mine. There, the official Eclipse-API classes were given. Another approach there would have been to use the `LaunchConfigurationFilteredTree` even if it is not official API. Is there a similiar class for the ExternalTools?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external tools dialog is still just launch configurations but only shows configurations where the launch configuration belongs to the `org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.launchGroup` launch group.

As usual the Eclipse code is very complex, but you can get the launch groups using

```
ILaunchGroup [] groups = DebugUITools.getLaunchGroups();
```

from the array you get find the group with the correct id.

You can get the launch group for an `ILaunchConfiguration` with

```
ILaunchGroup group = DebugUITools.getLaunchGroup(config, mode);
```

where the mode is always `"run"` for external tools.